# Problem with CSVParser: can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.iterable

Tags: java, xcode, eclipse, jboss, seam

I have a problem with java. I'm basically using the CSVParser library to read CSV files.
when I go to iterate a record it gives me the error. I'll post the code.

```
 Reader in = new FileReader(path);
        CSVParser parse = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader().withDelimiter(';').parse(in);
        
        
    for (CSVRecord record : parse) {
        

    }
```

Comment: "it gives me the error" what error?

Comment: What CSV library are you using? Add mention, link, tag.

Comment: Are you really using Xcode for Java? Is that relevant?

Comment: Is JBoss or Seam relevant?

Comment: I think we're supposed to get that the error message is, "can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.iterable".